# Prove that 012345678910111213 etc is not a periodic sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving, periodic-functions

Prove that the sequence $012345678910111213...$
(all non-negative integers written one by one in natural order) is not periodic.

I want to know the shortest and most elegant way to prove it. Can you help?

My proof:

Assume the sequence is periodic. Let $A$ be periodic subsequence with length $p$. Let $n$ be position of first occurrence of $A$. $A$ must contain at least 2 different digits, otherwise the tail of original sequence contains only single digit which is impossible, because any 2 consecutive integers have at least one different digit - last one. Let us take number $n$ such that it has only single digit in decimal notation, number of digits is more than $2p-1$ and it is more than a number that a digit at position $p + n - 1$ belongs to. We will get the contradiction proving that $n$ can not have all different digits because decimal notation of $n$ contains $A$. It is equivalent to the following lemma:

Lemma. Non-negative integers $n$ are colored: $1,2,..,k$ have color A; $k+1,k+2,..,2k$ have color B, etc. Prove that any $2k-1$ subsequent integers contains $k$ integers of the same color.

Proof. Let $c$ be number of different colors in subseqnece of $2k-1$ integers. If $c>2$ we immediately get desired subsequence - just take a subsequence with a color different from the colors of first and last elements. If $c=2$ we can note that there are only 2 ways to choose $2k-1$ subsequent integers from from $2k$ subsequent integers and in both cases it is clear that lemma is true, because first $k$ or last $k$ elements have the same color.

Comment: Let the period be $k$. Go to number $10^k$.

Comment: In fact, $0.1234567891011213...$ is not only irrational, but transcendental (it's called [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant)).

Comment: @user236182 it is sweet to know, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shortest proof I could think of: let the period be $k$, then $10^k$ contains $k$ sequential $0$s and thus all digits in the sequence are $0$s - which is absurd.

Comment: I do not think it is correct proof. But if you change $k+1$ to $2k-1$ I think it will be correct. If you can explain why it is correct for $k+1$ power please do it.

Comment: @Hedgehog Because "period of $(a_n)$ is $k>0$" means $\forall n, a_n=a_{n+k}$. Hence if we have $k$ $0$s in a row, all sequence must be $0$s.

Comment: @ok, got it, thanks.

Comment: I think this is not quite complete (as initially posted) because it is possible that the repeating subsequence starts _after_ the digits of $10^{k+1}$ have been appended. But if there is a repeating subsequence, it must start at _some_ digit, and there will always be a multiple of $10^{k+1}$ (with $k$ consecutive zeros) that is appended to the sequence later. By the way, any multiple of $10^k$ also contains $k$ consecutive zeros, so you could use $10^k$ instead of $10^{k+1}$.

Comment: @DavidK Initial question was about periodic sequence, not eventually periodic. And yes, $10^k$ has $k$ zeroes and not $k-1$, silly me. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Right, I've seen the corresponding "eventually periodic" question somewhere and that's what I was thinking of. So your answer is fine. And if someone wants to answer the slightly harder question, now they know how to do that, too.

Comment: the shortest demonstation is always the best

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is, that if we had a period of length k, then all k+1 digit long numbers would have to start and end with the same digit ( since their first and last digits are k digits apart) and that is nonsense.